# How do I use OpenPyXL for a specified range?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

How do I divide each value in one column by each value in a separate column?

Do I use the range function?

Example:

```
for i in range(2,80):
    sheet['D{}'.format(i)] = '=C1/E1, C2/E2, C3/E3, etc...'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done by applying division operations to the **actual** `values` of the cells. Your code is pretty close; you just need to correct the right hand side by accessing the cell values:

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('path/to/xl/file', read_only = False)

# Assuming you are working with Sheet1
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for i in range(2,80):
    try:
        sheet['D{}'.format(i)].value = int(sheet['C{}'.format(i)].value)/int(sheet['E{}'.format(i)].value)
    except ValueError:
        print("{} and/or {} could not be converted to int.".format(sheet['C{}'.format(i)].value, sheet['E{}'.format(i)].value))

wb.save('path/to/new/xl/file')
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  How do I convert 'str' to integer? I get the error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Are you sure that the contents of `C:C` and `E:E` are all numeric? If not, then converting cells to `int` is not going to help at all.

Comment: The contents in the range 2,80 are all numeric.

Comment: @applestooragnes, use `int()` to convert the strings to integers. I have edited the answer to add a `try-except` statement to handle the values that cannot be converted to `int`.

Comment: @applestooragnes, if this solved your problem please accept it as an answer for future users.